# deploy node application to google cloud from visual studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, publishing

I use Visual Studio to write node web apps and I'd like to deploy the code to google cloud directly from VS. Is it possible? (something like the publishing to Azure)?

Comment: to which service from google cloud do you want them uploaded?

Comment: I wold like to upload (publish) to an appengine.

Comment: The idea of this question is generic: I use Visual Studio to create a node website. I have a google cloud account and I want my website online (I don't know more about google cloud - I use azure for my other projects). How do I do this, simple and fast, directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: there is a [google cloud extension for VS](https://cloud.google.com/visual-studio/) but not sure if it supports publishing node apps to app engine